# Gas price error when minting a created token

Tags: solidity, gas-price, fees

I created the following token https://bscscan.com/address/0xb3497b2a0368e9b96ace9b6ad3033f440457d1b9.

In addition to the written code, the imported calls were ERC20 such as

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol; 
import @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol;
```

but the token was created correctly. However, when executing any function of the token, such as mint, for example, it gives a gas error, it returns the message shown in the image. Does anyone know the reason?[image]

Comment: paste the contract code.

Answer (score 0):

The gas error message you provided indicates that the transaction is running out of gas. Gas is a unit used in Ethereum to measure the computational effort required to execute transactions or perform actions on the blockchain.

There could be several reasons why you're encountering a gas error when executing functions of your token:

Insufficient gas limit: The gas limit is the maximum amount of gas you allocate for a transaction. If the gas limit is too low, it may not be enough to complete the execution of a function, resulting in an out-of-gas error. You can try increasing the gas limit when sending the transaction.

Infinite loop or excessive computation: If your contract contains loops or performs heavy computations, it can consume more gas than the block gas limit allows. Make sure your code doesn't have any infinite loops and optimize any computationally intensive operations.

Inconsistent or incorrect implementation: It's possible that there are issues in the code itself, such as incorrect usage of libraries, mismatched data types, or improper handling of gas costs. Review your code carefully, including the imported ERC20 libraries, to ensure everything is implemented correctly.

External contract interaction: If your contract interacts with other contracts, such as calling external functions or making transfers, those interactions can consume additional gas. It's important to check the gas requirements of the external functions and ensure that enough gas is provided when calling them.

To diagnose the specific reason for the gas error, you may need to provide more details about your code, including the specific function that's causing the issue and relevant parts of your contract implementation. Additionally, reviewing the transaction details on a blockchain explorer like BscScan can provide more insights into the gas usage and any potential errors or exceptions thrown during execution.

Comment: I took a good look at the code, but I couldn't find where this error might be occurring. The code is verified and public on BscScan. Could you please take a look? I will continue trying to resolve it on my end.

Comment: Hi CanardCoca! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange. It is against the site rules to use AI tools to generate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, you've already minted the max, you can't continue mint anymore.

```
    // Construtor para inicializar o token
    constructor(string memory _tokenImage) ERC20("babyshiba", "shiba2.0") {
        _mint(address(this), _maxSupply);  // Cria a quantidade máxima de tokens
        tokenImage = _tokenImage;  // Configura a imagem do token
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(totalSupply() + amount <= _maxSupply, "Total supply limit exceeded");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
```

Comment: So, my contract allows token transfers, but it is requiring an absurdly high gas value, and I don't understand the reason. For a simple transfer, it is demanding over $200 worth of gas.

Comment: Because there is no shiba coin under your account, all coins are under the contract account and cannot be transferred out (_mint(address(this), _maxSupply);). There is a problem with your code, please find a professional to review it.